# Altering ggplot2 plot using ggplot_build and use it in plot_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I want to alter a `ggplot2` plot in R using the `ggplot_build` and `ggplot_gtable` functions and use it afterwards in a `plot_grid`.

Example code to make the plot:

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(cowplot)

p1 <- ggplot(iris) +
  aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species) +
  geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(iris) +
  aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, colour = Species) +
  geom_point()

plot_grid(p1, p2)
```

Then I change p1 using ggplot_build and ggplot_gtable:

```
q1 <- ggplot_build(p1)
q1$data[[1]]$colour <- "black"
q1 <- ggplot_gtable(q1)
```

`plot(q1)` plots the plot that I want but I can not use it in `plot_grid` with `plot_grid(q1, p2)`. How can I solve this?

Edit: Code should have indeed worked. After a complete R restart everything worked as expected. Should have tried this first, apologies!

Comment: `cowplot::plot_grid(q1, p1, p2, ncol = 1)` works here.

Comment: Code should have indeed worked. After a complete R restart everything worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks for checking. The moderators will likely close this question, since it isn't based on a reproducible problem.

Answer (score 4):

When calling to print/plot a ggplot2, what really happens in the background is:

```
data <- ggplot_build(x)
gtable <- ggplot_gtable(data)
```

where `x` is your ggplot2 object (`p1` og `p2`). (See `ggplot2:::plot.ggplot`.)
Other routines uses `ggplotGrob(x)`, which is synonymous to `ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x))`.

Short story: `gtable` *is not* a ggplot2 object. It's a grob object. And there is not defined a plot or print method for grob objects. They must instead be drawn with the `grid` package.

To draw your `q1` and `q2`, use:

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(q1)
```

Comment: While this is correct, OP's code should also work. `plot_grid()` accepts gtables.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about grobs. Code indeed works now!

Answer (score 2):

Would you mind running your code through the [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) package and then posting the result here? Something isn't working right on your end. The code you post should work as expected (see below).

Note that I'm running the development version of cowplot, but the only visible difference is going to be the theme. Using gtables in `plot_grid()` has worked for years.

```r
library(ggplot2) 
library(cowplot)
#> 
#> 
#> *******************************************************
#> Note: cowplot does not change the default ggplot2 theme
#> anymore. To recover the previous behavior, execute:
#>   theme_set(theme_cowplot())
#> *******************************************************

p1 <- ggplot(iris) +
  aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species) +
  geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(iris) +
  aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, colour = Species) +
  geom_point()

plot_grid(p1, p2)
```

[image]

```r
q1 <- ggplot_build(p1)
q1$data[[1]]$colour <- "black"
q1 <- ggplot_gtable(q1)
plot_grid(q1, p2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Code should have indeed worked. After a complete R restart everything worked as expected.